# Fire Javascript only once after a record is created in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager code that is added to the `show` view. 
Simply I'd like this code to fire only once the record was created & the user is forwarded to the `show` view.

Comment: In your `create` action you could set a variable when record is created. Say, `@my_record_created = true`. Then in the view you simply guard on that variable: `<% if @my_record_created %> my google javascript here <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev but the instance `@my_record_created` was not passed from `create` to `show` view

Comment: Ah right, if you redirect, instance variables don't work. In this case, I'd use a query parameter or session key. Something like this: `redirect_to my_thing_path(@my_thing, created: true)`. Then you access it with `if params[:created]`

Comment: but this parameter will stay after page is viewed. So if the page was reloaded again the event will fire again. My first thought was to monitor the transition from  `create` to `show` but I'm still not sure if it's the right way.

Comment: Well, then session key. Just don't forget to unset the key when you read it.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev   I used the session key and it worked perfectly... Thanks